# How to access vertex normals from a shape-key in Python?

Tags: python, normals, shape-keys

I am experimenting with WebGL and I have a mesh that is animated via shape keys.

I can get access to the regular coordinates of the shape key pretty easily:

```
if bm.verts.layers.shape:
    skd_json = {}
    rval['shape_keys'] = skd_json
    for skn, sk_l in bm.verts.layers.shape.items():
        sk_v = [xyz for v in bm.verts for xyz in v[sk_l]]
        #sk_vn = [xyz for v in bm.verts for xyz in ???]
        sk_json = { 'vertices':sk_v,
        #'vertex_normals': sk_vn
        }
        skd_json[skn] = sk_json
```

However, the mesh I want to draw is smooth shaded, so I want to get the vertex normals for each of the shape keys so I can do some basic Phong shading even when the model is deformed.

How can I access these vertex normals via the python API?